# How can I open a Windows CMD window for Perl and run a command?

Tags: perl, cmd, window

Is there a way I can open a new cmd window and pass a variable and once completed close that window?

I have found some info but not enough that I can get it to work.

```
system('start "List Perl files" dir c:/dfd/dfdf.pl /B');
```

Opens window but does not run script.

Comment: Do you really want to open the window or is running the command enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main script:

```
my ($x, $y) = (888, 999);
system('start', 'List Perl files', 'perl', 'other_script.pl', $x, $y);
```

The other script:

```
print "Args received = @ARGV\n";
<STDIN>;
```

BTW, there's probably a better way to achieve your larger goals -- for example, organizing the needed functionality into modules. Passing information from one script to another via command-line arguments and `@ARGV` can be a hassle and a limiting factor.

Comment: how do I retrieve an array of vars... 
`foreach( @ARGV ) {
    print @_ . "\n";
}
<STDIN>;` ??

Comment: You can have problems with quotes in single argument `system`. Better use `system("start", "List Perl files", "perl", "other_script.pl", $x, $y);`.

Comment: @Phil See example of perl array loops in manual - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops