# How can I close a Windows CMD window after I run a Perl program?

Tags: perl, cmd, window

Is there a way to close a cmd window when a task is complete and also tell how many are already open?

```
system( qq{ start "List Perl files" perl c:/perlscripts/new_spider.pl $new_href } )
```

Comment: Can you please provide code using to open that window?

Comment: system( qq{ start "List Perl files" perl c:/perlscripts/new_spider.pl $new_href } );

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open a Windows CMD window for Perl and run a command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768241/how-can-i-open-a-windows-cmd-window-for-perl-and-run-a-command)

Comment: You are you opening a cmd window? You don't really need to do that to run a program.

Answer (score 1):

The command to close a window is

```
exit
```

However, when I tried your code (Win7) the cmd window closed without any help from me.

Take a look at new_spider.pl and double-check there's nothing holding the cmd window open in there.